# No such file or directory net/bpf.h

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to run the make command and I got the error

```
fatalerror: net/bpf.h: No such file or directory.
```

I looked up online and found this link : http://www.joewein.net/info/sw-net-bfh-error.htm

tried executing

```
ln -s /usr/include/pcap-bpf.h /usr/include/net/bpf.h
```

Please help me on how to resolve this error.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there's a typo in that instruction. It should be: `/usr/include/pcap/bpf.h` and not `/usr/include/pcap-bpf.h` since there's `bpf.h` file provided by the [`pcap` library](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bpf.h). So you need to install the library first:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

and then do:

```
ln -s /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h /usr/include/net/bpf.h
```

Comment: You sir are a pure genius :)